# Login script to show first name

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using a login script which works perfectly but I am struggling to understand how to set the first_name field form my user database to a session and become available to show, as far as I can see it uses the following function to make the login:

```
function login_check($mysqli) {
    // Check if all session variables are set 
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'], $_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['login_string'])) {
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $login_string = $_SESSION['login_string'];
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];

        // Get the user-agent string of the user.
        $user_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password  FROM members  WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1")) {
            // Bind "$user_id" to parameter. 
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
            $stmt->execute();   // Execute the prepared query.
            $stmt->store_result();

            if ($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
                // If the user exists get variables from result.
                $stmt->bind_result($password);
                $stmt->fetch();
                $login_check = hash('sha512', $password . $user_browser);

                if ($login_check == $login_string) {

                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Not logged in 
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                // Not logged in 
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            // Could not prepare statement
            header("Location: ../error.php?err=Database error: cannot prepare statement");
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        // Not logged in 
        return false;
    }
}
```

My initial attempt was to add the session variable inside of the `$_SESSION['login_string'])) {` but it wasnt to be and returns a null value. I can return the username and the user_id but nothing more?

Comment: if `login_check` returns true, you need to make a query to the database and get all the information for user with id = `$_SESSION['user_id']`. From there you will get the name and you must set it to session like `$_SESSION['first_name'] = $the_first_name_you_got_from_db;` after that you can simply do an `echo $_SESSION['first_name'];` to show the first name.

Comment: would this script be away from the script above?

Comment: the script you give in your question is not the script that logs someone in. it's a script that checks whether a user is already logged in.